# How to create a random number that unused in node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, koa

I try to create a random number with following code

```
let randomnumber = (Math.random().toString().slice(-8))
```

And I will check if the `mysql table` has this random number, if doesn't, this number will be inserted into the table, if do, run the above code again, and check again. like this

```
await mysqlModel.checkNumberExit([randomnumber])
.then(async(results) => {
 if (results.length === 0) {
    //doesn't exist, do something
 } else {
   //exist, repeat until the random number doesn't exist
 }
```

Here is my question, how can I do this function efficiently, this way I am using is very low efficiency, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to generate and check:

```
function getRandomNumber() {
   let randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random(1000,9999)*100000000);

    mysqlModel.find({"fieldName":randomnumber})
    .then(res => {
        if(!res) {
            //doesn't exist, do something
        }else{
            getRandomNumber();
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        //err
    });
}
```

call the function using:

```
getRandomNumber()
```